# Nodejs - Replacing all double word tags with a single word tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, tags

I have a string:

```
Const a = '<person>mark boby</person> bla bla 
<food>milk</food>'
```

And I need to turn it into:

```
'<person>mark</person> <person>boby</person> bla bla 
<food>milk</food>'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a custom [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), e.g:

```
const x = '<person>mark boby</person> bla bla <food>milk</food>';
x.replace(/<(\w+)>(.*?\s.*?)<\/\w+>/, (match, tag, value) =>
   value.split(' ')
        .map(val => `<${tag}>${val}</${tag}>`)
        .join(' '));
```

Comment: Great! But this works also on other matches, that srart with <person> and end with </food>

Comment: Well, for the given source string (`<person>mark boby</person> bla bla <food>milk</food>`) it appears to work as expected (i.e. the result is `<person>mark</person> <person>boby</person> bla bla <food>milk</food>`)

Is there a different source string?